# Angular translate pipe not working and not able to fetch data from JSON

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I have one module in my angular application called RecipeModule. In this module I am trying to use translate pipe but Pipe is not working. I saw many post on stackoverflow with similar  situation but it didn't worked for me.

My app.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AttractorComponent } from './attractor/attractor.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

// NG Translate
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';
//import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RecipeModule} from './recipe/recipe.module';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/locale/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AttractorComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule ,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxElectronModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    RecipeModule

  //  StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [TranslateService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

recipe.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RecipeDetailsComponent } from './recipe-details/recipe-details.component';
import { RecipeSearchComponent } from './recipe-search/recipe-search.component';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

export const RECIPE_ROUTES = [
    { path: 'recipe/search', component: RecipeSearchComponent },
    { path: 'recipe/details', component: RecipeDetailsComponent } 
];

@NgModule({
    declarations:[RecipeDetailsComponent, RecipeSearchComponent],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(RECIPE_ROUTES), TranslateModule, SharedModule]
})

export class RecipeModule{}
```

recipe-search.component.htmls is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    {{ 'SCREENS.SEARCH.TITLES' | translate }}
  </h1>
</div>
<p>recipe search screen</p>
```

My en.json is as follows:

```
{
    "SCREENS": {
        "SEARCH": {
            "TITLE": "Recipe Search works"
        },        
        "DETAILS": {
            "TITLE": "Recipe Details works!"
        }
   }
}
```

My shared module is as follows::

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';




@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule.forChild({})],
  exports: [TranslateModule]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

On gui , I am getting text from paragraph text on screen i.e recipe search screen but I am not able to get data from en.json using translate file. I am not getting any errors but still data from json is not visible. Please help

Comment: Where are you grabbing your data and how , Kindly show the file?

Comment: already added en.json file content

Comment: Not that i meant , I meant the file you are sending a request to ``en.json`` file and grabbing data out of it

Comment: code for reading file is in app.module.ts .. you can see above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question is asked many times on stackoverflow and many suggest using shared modules to solve this problem. But as per angular official documents shared modules are for optimization of angular application and to improve performance as by using shared modules we go for lazy loading of angular components.

For me the issue was not with translate pipe, it was a minor mistake in html page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error in html. You are writting TITLES in html but in the en.josn it is TITLE.